# How does network structure (model complexity) affects covergence speed?

Tags: neural-networks, convergence, recurrent-neural-network, attention

I trained Bi-GRU and HAN (Hierarchical Attention Networks) on my own datasets, and found HAN converges faster than Bi-GRU, within less number of epochs.

What would be the reason for this? I guess that this is related to the fact that HAN has more weights (thus more complex) than Bi-GRU.

Does complex models converge faster, or slower, than relatively simpler models? Any opinion? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more complex model usually converges slower, but a model whose inductive bias agrees better with the data often converges faster. Furthermore, modifications or additions to existing architectures (for example skip connections) are often made with the intent of pushing the model bias to better match the data, but at the same time increase the model complexity, so you observe both effects at once. So it's not so easy to say one way or another how the convergence speed changes.

Comment: Thank you. The idea of adding a bias that matches the data provides a new angle for my thinking.